# setTimeout and setInterval together -- repeating a pause

Tags: javascript

In javascript, I need to do the following, written in pseudocode:

```
REPEAT EVERY 5 SECONDS
    print 'One'
    wait 2.5 seconds
    print 'Two'
    wait 2.5 seconds
```

How can I do this? My (clumsy?) attempt follows:

```
a = setInterval(function() { 
     setTimeout(function(){print 'one'},0);
     setTimeout(function(){print 'two'},2500);
    },5000);
```

Improvements?

Comment: Are you asking about waiting for `2.5` seconds between `'one'` and `'two'` and then `7.5` seconds between `'two'` and `'one'` or are you asking about alternating between `'one'` and `'two'` every `2.5` seconds?

Answer (score 3):

```
var counter = 0;

setInterval(function() { 
     console.log( counter++ % 2 ? 'one' : 'two' );
}, 2500);
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RvVD7/

Comment: That achieves the desired output, but not the way the OP asked.

Comment: @RobG: Reading the question (not the title) carefully it looks like the OP doesn't specify a "way" of doing it. As such, this is a valid improvement to the OP's code and therefore a valid answer to his question.

Comment: There is not only the title, but also some psuedo code. It may well be what the OP really wanted what you wrote. Now s/he has two answers: one per the question, and one for how it probably should be done. You saved me writing the second. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Why you want to combine setTimeout and setInterval for this remains a mystery, but anyhow:

```
setInterval(function() {
  console.log('one');
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('two');
  },2500);
}, 5000);
```

Comment: How'd you propose to do this in a simple way?